# status of a service on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service

When I (on ubuntu) execute the the next commands I get status (written here as comment) that for first command ufw is running, and for the second command the ufw is inactive. How can I interpret that, is it the ufw running or not ?

```
service ufw status
# ufw start/running

ufw status verbose
# Status: inactive
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think, just because the service is running, it does not mean ufw is enabled. To answer your question, ufw is not running. You cannot use it configure rules. To use ufw, enable it first using,

```
sudo ufw enable
```

And then check with,

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Comment: So, to be sure the firewall is running, I have to do `service ufw enable` and `ufw  enable` ?

Comment: Service is already running based on your `sudo service ufw status` output. You just have to enable it. So, just do `sudo ufw enable`